# Email with php:[SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host]

Tags: php, email

I have search many similar questions asked before but I still cannot find the solving method for this. Sorry for asking this question.

Below is my php coding using to send email:

```
<?php
require("class.phpmailer.php"); // path to the PHPMailer class

$mail = new PHPMailer();  

$mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "testingtesting0330@gmail.com"; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "xxxxxxxx"; // SMTP password 

$mail->From     = "testingtesting0330@gmail.com";
$mail->AddAddress("testingtesting0330@gmail.com");  

$mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";
$mail->Body     = "Hi! \n\n This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.";
$mail->WordWrap = 50;  

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo 'Message was not sent.';
echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
?>
```

The class.phpmailer.php file is placed in the same file with the previous php document. I have also changed the content of class.phpmailer.php as follow:

```
  var $Host        = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';

  var $Port        = 465;
```

I have also change the content of php.ini:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 465

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = testingtesting0330@gmail.com
```

The openssl function is also enabled in php.ini:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

It also show openssl enabled in php info.

But after this, the error did show again. So, I would like to ask for the solution for this.

Also, if I need to connect to a certain SMTP server, only change the coding and php.ini is enough?

Thank you guy very much. This is very important to me and hope this problem can be solved.

> After you guy helping me, I have tried more method to solve the problem.
>
> I have change the SMTPSecure from "ssl" to "tls".
>
> $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
>
> The error change from "SMTP -> ERROR: Password not accepted from server" to "SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known"
>
> Further, if I changed the host from smtp.gmail.com to my IP address,
>
> the error became "ERROR: Failed to connect to server: connection attempt failed because the connection object has for some time did not respond correctly, or connection establishment failed because the host connection can not respond"
>
> Many thanks to all of you.

Comment: did you confirm that smtp.gmail.com is actually reachable from your host? your php code could be perfect, and the problem is somewhere farther upstream.

Comment: How can I confirm it is reachable from my host? I am new to php and the mail function. Sorry for asking that.

Comment: Try pinging it using command prompt or terminal.

Comment: You might want to use the debug output of the PHPMailer class: `$mail->Debugoutput = function($str, $level) { echo "$level: $str" . PHP_EOL; };` Also set the log level to 2: `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;`

Comment: +go to your google account and generate app password, because you can't login with your normal password to smtp

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Comment: SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP pe3sm3968732pdb.55 - gsmtp SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [210.3.224.222] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 SMTP -> ERROR: Password not accepted from server: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 pe3sm3968732pdb.55 - gsmtp SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250 2.1.5 Flushed pe3sm3968732pdb.55 - gsmtp

Comment: I have tried to use the two debug output and above is the result. Is it really related to the normal password I have been used? I tried to generate an app password but google said that I cannot use this setting. Many thanks to all of you.

Comment: I have also tried to ping smtp.gmail.com and it show the connection is fine.  Thanks.

Comment: Your initial host ('ssl://smtp.gmail.com'), port (465) and 'ssl' settings seem correct since it got you connected. Google may block your account until you 'solved' a captcha, see the 3rd point in the support-link: "If you're still having problems, visit http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and sign in with your Gmail username and password. If necessary, enter the letters in the distorted picture." Does that help?

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I have tried this but it still does not work. I think it is the problem of Gmail since it can send mail successfully using yahoo mail. Manys thank.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issues with the server firewall. Can you please try to stop server firewall for testing purpose and check this again.

Comment: I have tried to turn off the window firewall and run the coding again. But the same error is pop out again. Thank for helping me.